# P-channel MOSFET + op-amp ideal diode

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, low-power, ideal, p-channel

I'm replicating the [ideal diode circuit from Crutschow](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/articles/simple-inexpensive-ideal-diode-mosfet-circuits.817/).

[image]

I'm using the op-amp flavor in order to get a very low quiescent current.

The P-channel MOSFET will be a [NTMFS002P03P8ZT1G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntmfs002p03p8z-d.pdf).

My questions are :

- What characteristics should I look for in an op-amp for this circuit? As I understand it, it should be very low power (so long for the TLE2141CD I chose for prototyping). But should I worry about bandwidth or CMRR? And what about max. voltage (what margin should I take from the nominal 12 V)?
- The circuit by itself is only two components, it will be used at the output of a brick-type DC/DC so it shouldn't see any bad transients on its input, but should I worry about adding some protection components somewhere? What about the op-amp directly driving the P-channel gate, I take it the low op-amp current doesn't warrant a gate resistor?

Comment: Maximum solar cell voltage? Maximum and minimum battery voltage? Max current through the MOSFET? Speed of response? You'll need a current limiting resistor in series with the inverting input.

Comment: No Solar cell but a DC/DC converter output connected to a 12V battery
The DC/DC max. Power is 300W @12V so 25A continuous max. through MOSFET.
Speed of response should be fast enough to protect the DC/DC from being fried by having a reverse bias on its output... which is not saying much :-)

Comment: Why the current limiting resistor on the inverting input and not the on the non-inverting?
Also, aren't they supposed to be super high impedance ?

Comment: The inverting input, under rapid transient conditions, will rise significantly above the op-amp positive power rail and might destroy it. Why did you show a solar cell?

Comment: You might want to look for a comparator instead of an op-amp.

Comment: @Andyaka : it's the original schematic, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @JohnD : What difference is there between a comparator and an op-amp?

Comment: @VoltsAndNuts If you Google "op amp vs comparator" you'll find lots of references.